# OpenGL ES to Metal - Performance Bottleneck Differences

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, metal

I have been maintaining my own custom 2D library -written in Objective-C / OpenGL ES 2.0- for a while now, to use in my personal projects (not work). I have also tried *cocos2d* and *SpriteKit* now and then, but eventually settled for "reinventing the wheel" because

1. It's fun,
2. Knowledge-wise, I'd rather be the guy who can code a graphics library than just a guy who can use one,
3. Unlimited possibilities for customization.

Now, I am transitioning my code base to Swift and (besides all the design differences that arise when moving to a language where class inheritance takes a back seat to protocols, etc) I was thinking that while I'm at it, **I should consider transitioning to Metal as well**. If anything, for the sake of future-proofness (also, I'm all for learning new technologies, and to be sincere OpenGL/OpenGL ES are a terribly cluttered bag of "legacy" and backwards compatibility).

My library is designed around all sorts of OpenGL (ES)-specific performance bottlenecks: Use of texture atlases and mesh consolidation to reduce draw calls, rendering opaque sprites first, and semitransparent ones last (ordered back to front), etc.

My question is: Which of these considerations still apply to Metal, and which ones should I not even bother implementing (because they're not a performance issue anymore)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metal is only available on the subset of IOS devices which support OpenGLES3, so te be fair you need to compare Metal to GLES3.

**Texture atlases & mesh consolidation:**

With Metal, CPU cost of draw calls is lower than with GLES3, and you can parallelize draw call setup on multiple threads.

So this could allow you to skip atlasing & consolidation ... but those are good practices so it would be even better if you kept those with Metal and use the extra CPU time to do more things !

Note that with GLES3 by using instancing & texture arrays you should also be able to get rid of atlasing and keep a low draw call count.

**Rendering opaque sprites first, and semitransparent ones last**

Metal will change absolutely nothing to this, this is a constraint from the PowerVR GPUs tile based defered renderer, whatever driver you use this will not change the GPU hardware. And anyway rendering opaques before semi transparent is the recommended way to proceed when you do 3D, wheter you use DirectX, OpenGL or Metal ...

**Metal will not help if you are fillrate bound !**

In general, Metal will only give you improvements on the CPU side.
If your performance is limited by fillrate (fragment shaders too complex, too much transparent overdraw, resolution too high etc.) then you will get the exact same result in Metal and GLES3 (assuming that you have carefully optimized shaders for each platform).